# Is there a converse of the fact that a composition of proper morphisms is proper?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I know that the composition of proper morphisms is again a proper morphism (Lemma 49.37.4 in the Stacks Project). I'm curious if there is (at least a partial) converse, since I saw none mentioned there.

Suppose for instance you had two regular maps $\psi\colon X\to Y$ and $\phi\colon Y\to Z$ such that $\phi\circ\psi$ is a proper morphism. So I am wondering, is either $\phi$ and/or $\psi$ necessarily a proper morphism? Is there a proof of either of these claims, whether affirmative or negative?

Answer (score 1):

See Corollary II.4.8.e in Hartshorne:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be noetherian schemes.  If $f:X\to Y$ and $g: Y\to Z$ are two morphisms, if $g\circ f$ is proper, and if $g$ is separated, then $f$ is proper.

There may be a generalization in EGA.  In fact, this theorem is probably in the Stacks Project somewhere, but I can't find it quickly.

Comment: Here's the link to Stacks: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01W6 All facts like this seem to have the same proof though.

Comment: @Hoot The restriction to noetherian schemes in Hartshorne may just be an artifact of his use of the valuative criterion for discrete valuation rings only.  Otherwise, I can't figure out why the extra assumption is there.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that. Two proofs, then.